# Select any single element of my output to S4 mode

Tags: r

For compute ml estimate, i apply package  mle2{bbmle}.my output have S4 mode.I can't  select for '$' and '@' parameter estimation.
I require that select e.g. landa Estimate=   0.31148.
thanks for response.
Output:
    'Maximum likelihood estimation.

```
Call:
mle2(minuslogl = nsdlo, start = list(landa      = 0.01, teta = 1.001, 
alpha = 1.001, beta = 1.002), data =     list(x1 = dataset1, 
x2 = dataset2))

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(z)
landa  0.31148    9.83330  0.0317 0.9747
teta   0.95531   28.32446  0.0337 0.9731
alpha  0.93491   12.68511  0.0737 0.9412
beta   0.99756         NA      NA     NA

-2 log L: -0.00330078``
```

Answer (score 0):

To access coefficients use the `coef` function, see `?bbmle::mle2` for the following example:

```
x <- 0:10
y <- c(26, 17, 13, 12, 20, 5, 9, 8, 5, 4, 8)
d <- data.frame(x,y)
LL <- function(ymax=15, xhalf=6)
-sum(stats::dpois(y, lambda=ymax/(1+x/xhalf), log=TRUE))
fit1F <- mle2(LL, fixed=list(xhalf=6))
```

Get the first coefficient:

```
coef(fit1F)[1]
```

Or using `@`:

```
fit1F@fullcoef[1]
```